# Math application to calculate advance problems

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a math app in Ubuntu that it is easy to write and can calculate problems like stochastic processes in Probability Theories, ordinary differential equation and similar.

Comment: Did you already check the packages you can find in *Synaptics* package manager under the **Mathmatics** (normal/multiverse/universe) category? To be able to use it you need first to install it through `sudo apt-get install synaptics`. *Software Center* is great, but for those purposes *Synaptics* is still very handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for stochastic problems you'll do good with Octave (The apturl is actually for [QtOctave](http://qtoctave.wordpress.com:) which provides a very nice frontend for Octave) and Scilab ^1 plus [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) (they are first class applications), but if you search the software center, you'll probably find something more.

If your problem includes symbolic algebra, you could use [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) (or wxMaxima if you need a GUI).

I currently find that a nice combination of Maxima and Octave is basically unbeatable.

^1: If you need some high speed calculus (again, I don't know exactly what you need), let it be noted that [SciLab](http://www.scilab.org/) can export proyects from it's matlab-like language to C or Fortran...

You can install them using the software center, the console or any of the links below:

- [Octave](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/qtoctave) [image: Install qtoctave]
- [SciLab](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/scilab) [image: Install scilab]
- [wxMaxima](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wxmaxima) [image: Install wxmaxima]

***note:*** QtOctave is no longer being developed, but you can still download it through the software-center.

Comment: Since you have several of them, can you point them to their url homepages so it is easier to read the answer. +1 for the nice list. Although I also gave +1 to everyone else for the effort.

Comment: I edited the post too add some links (somehow I couldn't get the apturls working when adding them between lines...)

Answer (score 4):

I would advise you take a serious look at Sage, It is a Python based system that integrates GNU/Octave, Maxima and a host of other advanced math tools in one interface. Has a nice browser based notebook, read more:

**Home Page**

http://www.sagemath.org/

**Feature Tour**

http://www.sagemath.org/tour.html

It is a large download, and not in the repositories but has some advantages of providing more updated versions of the support packages.

Comment: There is a PPA available: https://launchpad.net/~aims/+archive/sagemath.

Answer (score 2):

**Octave**

http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/ (Available in the repositories as `octave3.2`)

A colleague of mine recommended this. It's basically an open-source version of MATLAB. (So, numeric approximations, not exact.) You can certainly use this for stochastic processes and differential equations, but I don't know if it fits "easy to write"

Disclaimer: I have not actually used this myself.

Comment: Don't worry about the easy. I meant that I could write the equations like in a notebook.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an advanced Computer Algebra System that can perform symbolic calculations, one of the best open source available for Linux is Maxima, that has a nice graphical interface called `wxmaxima`:

[image]